# How much entanglement does each quasiparticle carry?

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, non-equilibrium, quasiparticles

The dynamics of entanglement entropy $S$ out of equilibrium can be understood in some regimes from the point of view of the quasiparticle picture: an excited state acts as a source of pairs of quasiparticles with opposite momenta which are entangled, and since they are assumed to travel ballistically, they generate a linear growth of $S$ as they leave the partition of the system. Eventually, when the farthest quasiparticle has left the partition, $S$ saturates to a constant value. To the best of my knowledge, this was first proposed [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-5468/2005/04/P04010).

My question is: is there a more quantitative way of understanding this approach? For instance, if I know precisely the shape of the distribution of the excitations, i.e. $n(k)=\langle \psi|\hat{a}_k^\dagger \hat{a}_k|\psi\rangle$, where $\hat{a}_k^{(\dagger)}$ annihilates (creates) a quasiparticle excitation, can I predict exactly how much entanglement will each excitation carry, and therefore make predictions about eg. the slope of the linear growth, or the saturation value of entanglement entropy, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}S$?